# multiple geometry clips on a UIElement

Tags: c#, geometry, clip, uielement

I am using C#, Silverlight, Visual Studio for Windows Phone 7.

Is there a way to give a `UIElement` multiple Geometry clips? Something equivalent to:

```
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Data = myRectangle; // say of size 100x100
myPath.Clip = myClipRect; // smaller rectangle, say of size 20x20, located at (0,0)
myPath.Clip = myClipEllipse; // circle of radius 30, centered on myRectangle
```

Right now, myClipEllipse will override myClipRect in myPath.Clip, so only myClipEllipse will be displayed.  I'm looking for a result that draws myRectangle with both of these clips correctly (ie, not inverted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using a `GeometryGroup` class ([docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrygroup(v=vs.95).aspx)). Just put all the geometries as children of the `GeometryGroup`, and give this `GeometryGroup` to the Clip.