# transforming the Clip of a UIElement

Tags: silverlight, geometry, transform, clip, uielement

I am using C#, Silverlight, Visual Studio for Windows Phone 7.

I would like to get the Clip of a `UIElement` that includes any transform that has been done on the `UIElement`.

This example gives me the Clip but does not include any transform from the UIElement:

```
// uie is a UIElement taken from a PhoneApplicationPage
Geometry myClip = uie.Clip;
```

I tried the following, but it ended up moving the `UIElement`:

```
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
var page = frame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
GeneralTransform gt = uie.TransformToVisual(page);
uie.RenderTransform = gt as Transform;
Geometry myClip = uie.Clip;
```

I also tried to add an inverse transform at the end to undo any movement, but that seemed to make it worse:

```
uie.RenderTransform = gt.Inverse as Transform;
```

Please help me get the Clip with the original transform of the `UIElement` without messing with the `UIElement` itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this without messing with the original `UIElement`. I needed to create a new `Geometry` object with the same data rather than using the original `Geometry`. Not only does this separate the new data from the old data, it also prevents an object from possibly getting assigned as a child to multiple objects.

Here is the resulting code I used:

```
var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
var page = frame.Content as PhoneApplicationPage;
GeneralTransform gt = uie.TransformToVisual(page);
var place = gt.Transform(new Point());
// declaring new variables to hold these values
Geometry geom;
Path path = new Path();
// here I checked for other restrictions on my UIElements before assigning the variables
geom = new RectangleGeometry();
(geom as RectangleGeometry).Rect = new Rect(place.X, place.Y, uie.RenderSize.Width, uie.RenderSize.Height);
path.Data = geom;
```

I mentioned that I check for some restrictions on my UIElements before assigning the variables. This is related to another question I posted about clips ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896493/multiple-geometry-clips-on-a-uielement)).